# Nativescript custom property not accessible

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to create a custom component in Nativescript. The component works fine with the static data, I want to add some custom properties to that control, but the are not accessible in the code behind. I am trying to create a MCQ like box or a something similar to radio control, so user can only select one option from the given ones.

CustomControl.xml

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="form" loaded="loaded">
  <Repeater items="{{ items }}">
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical" tap="itemTapped" id="{{id}}">
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" verticalAlignment="center">
            <Label text="{{text}}" class="form-field" width="88%"/>
            <Label text="{{characterCode}}" visibility="{{visible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}" class="icon"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="separator"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
 </Repeater>
 </StackLayout>
```

CustomControl.js

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

var _component;
var _viewModel = new Observable();
var _selectedId = null;

exports.loaded = function(args){

  _component = args.object;

  //passing in _component.items as array throws undefined 
  var items = getInitializedArray(["Some text","Someother text"]);
  _viewModel.set("items", items);

  _component.bindingContext = _viewModel;

}


exports.itemTapped = function(args){
  var id = args.object.id;

  if(_selectedId === null){
    var item = _viewModel.get("items").getItem(id);
    item.visible = true;
    _viewModel.get("items").setItem(item, id);

  }else{
    var item = _viewModel.get("items").getItem(_selectedId);
    item.visible = false;

    item = _viewModel.get("items").getItem(id);
    item.visible = true;
    _viewModel.get("items").setItem(item, id);
  }
  _selectedId = id;
}

function getInitializedArray(data){
  var id=0;
  var items = data.map((listItem) => {
    return {
      text: listItem,
      characterCode: String.fromCharCode(0xea11),
      visible: false,
      id: id++
    }
  });
  return new ObservableArray(items);
}
```

Trying to use it in my page as

```
<CustomComponents:CustomControl items="{{items}}"/>
```

But using args.object.items throws undefined property for object.

I have read that I'll have to use dependency-observable and will have to create a plugin. But I am not using any platform specific thing, I am just creating a component with existing ui components and its pretty simple what I want to achieve. Is there a way to bind custom properties? Plugins are too complex for this, How can I achieve it?

Comment: I think this discussion will be helpful for you https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1620#issuecomment-188671352   overall what you are trying to achive shoudl be done with code-behind only

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs and going through various forums and github issues following is what I have found and thanks to Nick lliev' comment.

To give custom properties to your controls you'll have to use the code only technique, I have written a blog http://mobile.folio3.com/creating-custom-controls-in-nativescript/ describing both the techniques showing how to give custom properties to your custom controls.